# Bad substitution: Bringing key in env over to yml file

Tags: environment-variables, yaml, cypress, circleci

I am currently running tests from Cypress in CircleCI for my project. I have my record key for Cypress and I need to store it in an `process.env` file and bring it over to my `config.yml` file.

I can't really find anything too specific to my need.

**I am getting an error as well:**

`/bin/bash: ${process.env.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY}: bad substitution`

Here is my code:

`.circleci/config.yml/`

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/browsers:chrome67
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm ci
          paths:
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache
      - run: npm install --save-dev cypress
      - run: node_modules/.bin/cypress verify
      - run: node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome --record ${process.env.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY}
```

`.env`

```
CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY = <my_key_here>
```

Re-tried it by moving things around and still gets same error:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/browsers:chrome67
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: 
          name: "setup custom environment variables"
          command: 
            echo ${process.env.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY} >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm ci
          paths:
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache
      - run: npm install --save-dev cypress
      - run: node_modules/.bin/cypress verify
      - run: node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome --record $BASH_ENV
```

Not sure how to correctly bring it over.

Comment: Are you able to store your environment variables in the CircleCI env vars UI? It's in Project Settings -> Environment Variables. If you can do that, you can get rid of the "setup custom environment variables" section, and just reference the variable name where you need it.

Comment: Incidentally, you can't set up env vars in one `run` section and then use them in another - each step gets a clean shell.

Comment: I did get it all set up in the env variables in the project, but then read that headless Chrome still does not support recording even though I have a record key.

Answer (score 0):

As of 7/9/2019 Cypress still does NOT support headless Chrome (which is what runs in the command line only) being recorded. Even though I have the record key I cannot use it because they still have not been able to have headless Chrome support recording or anything like Electron can when in headless mode.

My only solution is that I run tests I want recorded locally but other than that I am just letting them pass in the command line and hoping Cypress just implements recording soon.